# How to Animate the TextView within the Custom Dialog Box Android(Not DialogBox)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialog

I'm trying to animate the TextView which is within the Custom Dialog Box. **I dont want to animate the Dialog box**, I have searched but all i found is Animate the Dialog box, not item in it.

```
    TextView txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             Animation mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 599, 0, 0);
                mAnimation.setDuration(10000);
                mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
                mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
                mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
                txt.setAnimation(mAnimation);
```

I'm able to Animate the TextView with this code in the Layout which is not a dialog box, i am also able to Show the Text in the Dialog box, But i want to Animate the Text in the Dialog Box, when i run the code, i get **Unfortunately, App has Stopped**

Any help, I tried the onCreateDialog function, but got that its Deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your `TextView` instance refer to the one inside the Dialog:

```
TextView txt=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

What you are doing is searching for in the main `Layout` and it may not exist, so your App exits